# how to create DatePicker with plus minus sign in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am creating an application in which I am using androids DatePicker.I want the DatePicker to have plus and minus sign rather then the spinner view.can anybody tell me how to get it. 
The datepicker that i have used has got spinner view.I am new in android development so please if somebody knows the answer, help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your targetSdkVersion attribute set to in your manifest?

Comment: my targetSdkversion is set to 17 and minSdkVersion is set to 8

Comment: are you using a Holo Theme?

Comment: i am using Theme.light. does it has to do something with theme? actually i am upgrading an existing application whose manifest file was already defined. the theme being used by the application is defined in the styles.xml file.

Comment: the application theme is @style/AppTheme and so is the activity theme. here is the styles file if you can figure out something from it:

Comment: the application theme is @style/AppTheme and so is the activity theme. actually i just checked it properly and figured out that on devices with api level 10 and below the application uses Theme.Light,for api 11 and above it uses Theme.Holo.Light and for api 14 and above it uses Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Try this to specify the theme for your dialog on Android Honeycomb+, in this example the Holo.Light theme:

```
    DatePickerDialog datePicker;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {
    .
    .
    .
    };

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
    {
     datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, dateSetListener, ...)
    }
    else
    {
     // specify the Holo Light Theme for this dialog on Honeycomb+
     datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, DatePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, dateSetListener, ...)
    }

    datePicker.show();
```

Comment: but actually your suggestion helped me to figure out what the problem is.its because of the theme that i am using.the plus minus datepicker view is an old designed and appears with a plus minus on devices having api level lower then 11 or if we set our applications theme to android:theme.light. thanks anyways for your help @CSmith